# Unable to import module 'lambda': No module named 'paramiko'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python lambda function, which will ssh into an ec2 instance and execute few linux commands related to Elastic Search. My lambda function is :

```
import boto3
import paramiko
def worker_handler(event, context):

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    #Download private key file from secure S3 bucket
    s3_client.download_file('clinicdoc','backupkey.pem', '/backupkeyAccess.pem')

    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/backupkeyAccess.pem")
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    host=event['myIP']
    print ("Connecting to" + host)
    c.connect( hostname = host, username = "ec2-user", pkey = key )
    print ("Connected to " + host)

    commands = [
        "ls"
        ]
    for command in commands:
        print ("Executing {}".format(command))
        stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
        print (stdout.read())
        print (stderr.read())

    return
    {
        'message' : "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output"
    }
```

The zip file is already created and upload to lambda and when I checked in pip list, the package paramiko is already installed:

```
Package         Version
--------------- -------
appdirs         1.4.4
bcrypt          3.2.0
boto3           1.17.97
botocore        1.20.97
cffi            1.14.5
cryptography    3.4.7
distlib         0.3.2
filelock        3.0.12
jmespath        0.10.0
paramiko        2.7.2
pip             21.1.2
pycparser       2.20
pycryptodome    3.10.1
PyNaCl          1.4.0
python-dateutil 2.8.1
s3transfer      0.4.2
setuptools      56.0.0
six             1.16.0
urllib3         1.26.5
virtualenv      20.4.7
wheel           0.36.2
```

But when the function is triggered, it's throwing an error :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda': No module named 'paramiko'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Could you please help here as I'm looking for long time and no any solution.

Comment: **Side-note:** Using SSH from Lambda is a strange use-case. If your goal is to execute scripts on an Amazon EC2 instance, I would recommend using [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). It can run commands simultaneously on many instances (and even on-premises computers if they have the Systems Manager agent installed) and access is tracked in CloudTrail.

Comment: SSM not working for me ... that's why I goes with traditional way which should works also ?